# CodedUI test: recognize html entities character

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

On my CodedUI test i am doing this string comparison: "Provider  BAO" but in application the string looks like this: "Provider&nbsp BAO" with this, the test doesn't understand the string.
how to do test understand this string? Ps: The string is allocated on combobox field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  
**HttpUtility.HtmlDecode** method to covert 
"Provider&nbsp BAO" to " "Provider BAO"

You will need to import System.Web namespace.